# Blender ID Authentication - Issue with Login

Tags: blender-id

I just joined Blender Cloud and I am trying to login with 'Blender ID authentication' add-on so I can activate the 'Blender Cloud' add-on. I am having trouble logging in however. I reinstalled and it did not fix the issue. Also I just upgraded to 2.79 on windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about Blender Foundation payed service

Comment: Blender cloud is a subscription service,they should provide support for any issues you are having

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a Blender Institute paid service; just send an email to cloudsupport@blender.org

Comment: Oh, right sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

If you have any issues, contact us at cloudsupport@blender.org. Stack Overflow is not the place for this.